# Возможно ли добавление дополнительных разрешений в манифест после выгрузки приложения в плеймаркет?

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

Собственно вопрос в заголовке, возможно ли добавление дополнительных разрешений в манифест когда приложение уже загружено в плеймаркет. Знаю что возможно в дальнейшем разрешение на платежи в плеймаркете возможно добавлять после выгрузки, но как насчёт других разрешений например на чтение и запись на диск и тд, более серьёзные пермишены? П.С:Если вопрос задавался скиньте ссылку на ответ, что то не нашёл. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких ограничений нет. Вы можете свободно добавлять и удалять любые разрешения.

Единственный нюанс - обновление с добавлением разрешения на чтение СМС могут не пропустить и потребовать от вас обоснования необходимости этой функции. Причём обоснование должно быть супер железным. Большей части приложений его получить не разрешают.

Comment: Понял спасибо за ответ, просто приложение у меня пока не задействует все функции, которые в дальнейшем будут доделываться, и подумал если сразу указать разрешения возникнет больше вопросов, о том что в приложении они не используются.

Comment: @fadey, в теории да, если всё сразу добавить, то у модерации могут возникнуть вопросы. А т.к. там роботы модерируют, то приложение и акк могут моментально забанить. Хотя конкретных случаев подобных я и не припомню.